# Wrtie a script to Delete files if it exists in different folder in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying write a script in linux. Where I have some csv files in Two different folders(A and B) and then after some processing copy of rejected files are moving to Bad Folder.

SO I want bad files to be deleted from Table A and B which have copied to Bad Folder.

Can you help me to write this script for linux?

Best

Comment: What did you try already? Please, show it so we can actually help you instead of writing the script for you. SO is not a free resource to get your code written.

Answer (score 1):

lets say name of Bad Folder is 'badFolder' and considering 'A', 'B' and 'badFolder' are in same directory

Steps to delete files from folder A and B:

step 1: change current directory to your 'badFolder'

**cd badFolder**

step 2: delete identical files

**find . -type f  -exec rm -f ../A/{} \;**

**find . -type f  -exec rm -f ../B/{} \;**

The argument **-type f** tells to look for files, not directories.

The **-exec ... \;** argument tells that, once it finds a file in 'badFolder', it should run the command rm -f on its counterpart in the A subdirectory.

Because rm is given with the -f option, it will silently ignore files that don't exist.

Also, it will not prompt before deleting files. This is very handy when deleting a large number of files. However, be sure that you really want to delete the files before running this script.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Set the working folder in which you want to delete the file
Working_folder=/<Folder>/<path>
cd $Working_folder
#command to delete all files present in folders
rm <filenames seperated by space>
echo "files are deleted"
#if you want to delete all files you can use wild card character 
# e.g. command rm *.* 

# if you want to delete a particular file say for deleting .csv file you can use command rm *.csv command
```

Comment: use `cd "${Working_folder}"` instead: there a bunch of possible failures if you leave it this way. Asides from this - answer doesn't really address what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Set variables containing the paths of your A, B and BAD directories.

Then you can do something along the lines of

```
for file in ls ${PATH_TO_BAD}
do
rm ${PATH_TO_A}/$file
rm ${PATH_TO_B}/$file
done
```

This is iterating over the BAD directory and any file it finds, it deletes from the A and B directories.